# Display information on a page based on a role within JWT token (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router, jwt

I have a NodeJS backend and a ReactJS frontend. On the back I use a **jwt token** to store the user's role after they've logged in. On the front I use react-router with a custom protected route component in order to re-direct the user to the homepage if they haven't authenticated themselves, and I save the jwt token on state.

Let's say that I have a page that greets the user depending on his role `Hi! seller` or `Hi! buyer`, the role is taken from the jwt token that's on state (I save it using context). In order for me to get this role I'd have to decode this token, in my case I use [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode). My question is: *is it save to decode the token from the frontend? If not, what alternatives do I have?* I'm not doing any requests to the backend and that's why I'm decoding it from the frontend, when normally each request should verify the token's validity.

My goal here is to display *slightly* different information depending on the user's role using simple if/else ternary conditionals (can be a buttons, some text, some different styling, etc...) and doing so in a secure way, and I'm not sure if decoding the token from the frontend is okay.

Comment: You can do it in the front-end if your API clearly secured datas send to the user and requests accepted. As you said, you'll just use it for customisation.

Comment: Thanks @farvilain! i just wanted to make sure that it was an-okay approach. If you want to elaborate in the answer I'll gladly accept it as a solution.

Comment: Just consider you successfully hacked your own site. You're now considered, falsy, as a buyer or seller... do you have access to some private data? No, because the API is secured (I hope for you), so it will not work. If there is no special API, you see the same data. So the difference is just about presentation. Well, everybody with enough patience/skill can hack your React JS code in google dev console. It is not a security breach.